# Difference between simply import string const and Dependency Injection Angular

Tags: angular, import, dependency-injection, code-injection

I'm trying to dive into Angular Dependency Injection and I can't understand the difference between just importing a const/variable and using Angular DI.

Example:

- I have a file variables.ts where I have this code:

  ```
  import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

  export const API_URL = 'www.com.com.ar'
  export const API_URL2 = new InjectionToken<string> 
  ('www.com.com.arAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
  ```
- Let's check our app.component.ts:

  ```
  import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
  import { API_URL, API_URL2 } from './varToExporit/variables';

  @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
   providers: [
     {provide:API_URL2, useValue:'www.com.com.arASDASD'}
   ]
  })
  export class AppComponent {

   title = '';
   exportedVariable:string = '';
   exportedVariable2:string = ''; 

   constructor(@Inject(API_URL2) private apiURL2: string) {
     this.exportedVariable = API_URL;
     this.exportedVariable2 = apiURL2;
   }
  }
  ```

What is the advantage of using **this.exportedVariable2**? I do not understand the difference of just using the imported API_URL const imported here:
  `import { API_URL, API_URL2 } from './varToExporit/variables';`

Also, I have no idea why it's showing the value:
  `'www.com.com.arASDASD'`  
and not  `'www.com.com.arAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'`   
but I guess I have to dive more into providers types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are effectively asking is *What is the purpose of dependency injection?* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) will give you a good extensive answer to that question. One of dependency injection's benefits that I want to draw your attention to is [testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Testing). The direct answer to your question from the perspective of testing is that an injection token allows you to inject a different value in your unit tests compared to your production code. That means that if you want to use a different constant in your tests than in your production code, an injection token allows you to do that.

You may be interested in the [Testing Component with a dependency](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency) documentation. The example in the documentation shows a test-double being provided for the `UserService`. If you were to write a unit test for your `AppComponent`, you'd be able to provide a test-double for the `API_URL2` injection token in the same manner.

Example:

```ts
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [ AppComponent ],
   providers: [ { provide: API_URL2 , useValue: 'my-test-double-value'} ],
});
```

## Edit

Because you are providing the `API_URL2` injection token in the component instead of the module, the example above is not 100% correct. Please refer to the [Override component providers](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#override-component-providers) documentation to learn about dealing with that scenario.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying, now I understand some use cases for the type providers.